# How to change the orientation of view in Xamarin.Forms without rotating the device?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I need to change the orientation of the view in Xamarin.Forms without rotating the device, so that the view should layout as like in the landscape mode.

Is there any way to achieve it? either in Xamarin.Forms or in Xamarin.iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **iOS** in a **Dependency Service** write the below method

```
public void ChangeLandscapeOrientation()
 {
     UIDevice.CurrentDevice.SetValueForKey(new NSNumber((int)UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft), new NSString("orientation"));
     UINavigationController.AttemptRotationToDeviceOrientation();
 }
```

Call the **ChangeLandscapeOrientation** method wherever you need it.

In **AppDelegate.cs**

```
public override UIInterfaceOrientationMask GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations(UIApplication application, UIWindow forWindow)
{

    var mainPage = Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.MainPage;

    if (mainPage is YourPage || (mainPage is NavigationPage &&
                                   ((NavigationPage)mainPage).CurrentPage is YourPage) || (mainPage.Navigation != null &&
                                                                                             mainPage.Navigation.ModalStack.LastOrDefault() is YourPage))
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Landscape;
    }
    else
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: This code works in simulators but not in devices. Any idea?

Comment: @Divakar I have added the code to write in AppDelegate also. Try it!

Comment: That override not even hit in both while application is loading and while changing the orientation manually

Comment: You mean breakpoint right? Yes, I have put the breakpoint there and checked. The override not called.

Comment: @Divakar It is a default override method which gets called even without orienting your device or simulator. Can you check your info.plist Supported interface orientations.

Comment: Yes. Now the override getting called while application loading. But even now the orientation not changed in device upon button click

Comment: That override getting called only for simulators. For device, that override not even called.

Comment: I found one more thing. Only iPad device and simulators are not rotated. If I rotate the iPad device physically, then it rotated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174829/discussion-between-divakar-and-ramya).